# How to share code between methods having binary actions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Sorry for the title, I cannot come out with anything concise, please feel free to edit a better one.*

I want to write switch-like methods (`.on()` and `off()`) similar to the code below:

```
class Hello:

    def on(self):
        self.say(1)

    def off(self):
        self.say(2)

    def say(self, param):
        # a lot of code common to .on() and .off()
        # specific code for .() and .off()
        if param == 1:
            print("hello")
        if param == 2:
            print("goodbye")
        # more code common to both cases

h = Hello()
h.on()
h.off()
```

`.on()` and `.off()` share a lot of code which I would like to reuse (= not duplicate it between the methods) but the two-stage approach above seems akward.

**Is there a better way to share code between methods?**

The two more ideas I came with (but do not know whether they are implementable) are:

- a catch-all method which would know how it was called and make decisions based on that
- a way to tell a method: "when you are called, do *this* (shared code), then run the code below (specific code) and then *that*  (again, shared code)"

Comment: you can print those lines in `on` and `off` and only leave the common code in `say`. That way you won't need the `param` argument

Comment: @EliKorvigo: there is shared code before and after the specific part, so i would need to have two "shared" methods.

Comment: You should put the specific code into the specific methods. And it might also be a good idea to use a dictionary for your text instead of multiple `if`: `answers = {'on': 'hello', 'off': 'goodbye'}; print(answers.get(state))`.

Comment: @WoJ then I would pass the message you want to print instead of the obscure `param`, e.g. `def off(self): self.say('goodbye')`. Then there will be no specific code left in `say`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most pythonic way would be to use a decorator

```
from functools import wraps

def _say(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("set up")  # preprocessing code
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)  # unique code
        print("tear down")  # postprocessing code
    return inner

class Hello:

    @_say
    def on(self):
        print("hello")

    @_say
    def off(self):
        print("goodbye")
```

Usage

```
Hello().on()
set up
hello
tear down

Hello().off()
set up
goodbye
tear down
```

Note that communicating data between `inner` and `func` will need to be passed as arguments / return values.

---

Another classic way would be to forgo individual methods and instead just use a method with an argument (which could be a bool, a string or an Enum) like so:

```
from enum import Enum

class State(Enum):
    OFF = 0
    ON = 1

class Hello:

    def say(self, state):
        print('set up')
        if state == State.ON:
            print('hello')
        elif state == State.OFF:
            print('goodbye')
        else:
            raise ValueError
        print('tear down')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two patterns that you can use here, one is decorators the other is context managers:

Let's implement the context manager:

```
import contextlib

class Hello:

    def on(self):
      with self.say():
        print("hello")

    def off(self):
        with self.say():
          print("goodbye")

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def say(self):
        # a lot of code common to .on() and .off()
        # specific code for .() and .off()
        print("before code")
        yield
        print("after code")
        # more code common to both cases

h = Hello()
h.on()
h.off()
```

By implementing say as a context manager it allows us to run setup code and teardown code easily.

Answer (score 0):

New attempt:

```
class wrap:

    before = "_before"
    after = "_after"

    def __init__(self, before=None, after=None):
        if before is not None:
            self.before = before
        if after is not None:
            self.after = after

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(wrapped_self, *a, **kw):
            getattr(wrapped_self, self.before)()
            result = func(self, *a, **kw)
            getattr(wrapped_self, self.after)()
            return result

        return wrapper


class Example:
    def _before(self):
        print("before")

    def _after(self):
        print("after")

    def say_done(self):
        print("done")

    @wrap()
    def hello(self, name):
        print("hi", name)

    @wrap(after="say_done")
    def goodbye(self, name):
        print("goodbye", name)


Example().hello("Woj")
Example().goodbye("Woj")
```